# GCP App Engine Firewall Rules Failing For Custom Domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firewall, app-engine-flexible

My goal is to limit access to my App Engine Service to my home office IP. I have configured the App Engine Firewall with *allow* rules for both my IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, and set the *default* rule to *deny*.

This works when browsing my application using the unique appspot.com address assigned to my app. But attempting to access my application using the custom domain I have configured for App Engine, is resulting in a 403.

I have further verified that the rules are working as intended on the appspot.com domain. Anything that isn't in my allow list is getting the 403 as intended.

This tells me that my rules are "working," but I am unable to find any reference as to why this would not influence access to my application through the configured custom domain.

Note: when the default rule is set to *allow*, my application *does* work using the custom domain, so I am certain that configuration is sound.

Are custom domains simply beyond the scope of App Engine's Firewall? I was hoping to avoid digging into the VPC configuration for now.

Firewall Rules
[image: Firewall Rules Screenshot]

Custom Domain Config
[image: Custom Domain Config]

Edit: Log shows my IPv6 IP address as the requesting IP when tailing the log:

```
  {
  "entries": [
    {
      "insertId": "dlpqxpfa090t8",
      "jsonPayload": {
        "appLatencySeconds": "0.011",
        "trace": "b7f63eb3d2fb4c52480253c224821a23",
        "latencySeconds": "0.011"
      },
      "httpRequest": {
        "requestMethod": "GET",
        "requestUrl": "/users/kind/add",
        "status": 200,
        "responseSize": "4810",
        "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.81 Safari/537.36",
        "remoteIp": "2600:****:****:****:****:****:****:9936",
        "referer": "https://f******s.e******t.com/users",
        "latency": "0.011s",
        "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
      },
      "resource": {
        "type": "gae_app",
        "labels": {
          "zone": "",
          "project_id": "f*******s",
          "version_id": "20220801t212517",
          "module_id": "default"
        }
      },
      "timestamp": "2022-08-09T22:11:33.869Z",
      "labels": {
        "appengine.googleapis.com/trace_id": "b*****************a23",
        "appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name": "aef-default-2*********7-770v",
        "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "0**********3",
        "compute.googleapis.com/resource_id": "21*********29",
        "compute.googleapis.com/zone": "********"
      },
      "logName": "projects/f********s/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request",
      "trace": "projects/f*********s/traces/b7f63eb3d2fb4c52480253c224821a23",
      "receiveTimestamp": "2022-08-09T22:11:38.104875464Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit 2: As suggested in the comments, I tried hitting a URL w/ curl. Below is the result:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.856]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\shawn>curl
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information

C:\Users\shawn>curl https://f*****s.e*******t.com/index

    <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head>
    <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
    <h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
    <h2>Access is forbidden.</h2>
    <h2></h2>
    <script defer src="https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js/v652eace1692a40cfa3763df669d7439c1639079717194" integrity="sha512-Gi7xpJR8tSkrpF7aordPZQlW2DLtzUlZcumS8dMQjwDHEnw9I7ZLyiOj/6tZStRBGtGgN6ceN6cMH8z7etPGlw==" data-cf-beacon='{"rayId":"738c818088a17d62","version":"2022.6.0","r":1,"token":"c070c2d4c5ad48d18815371af21d9e80","si":100}' crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body></html>
    
    C:\Users\shawn>
```

NOTE: I thought I was on to something with IPv6 being the culprit, but I've since disabled IPv6 completely and https://whatismyipaddress.com/ is showing that I'm not broadcasting an IPv6 address any longer. Still no dice.

Comment: Can you set all traffic to allow, access via your custom domain and log the IP address it shows (this is to confirm it's the same ip address as when you access it via the ```appspot.com``` domain)

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. Both App Engine firewall rules and Custom Domain settings are global to the App Engine project. There doesn't appear to be a discrete configuration for Firewall or Custom Domain within a project.

Comment: What i meant was - allow all traffic i.e. delete all rules in Firewall for app engine. Then in your code, add something to log/print the IP of incoming request. Then access your appspot.com end point and your custom domain endpoint. Then compare the IPs. If the IPs are the same, then you know something is going on at the Firewall rules end. If they are not, then it means traffic is being bounced/routed from your custom domain to appspot somehow which changes the IP

Comment: Sorry, @NoCommandLine I misunderstood. I set the rule to allow and tailed the App Engine logs using `gcloud app logs tail --log-http`. Confirmed that App Engine is seeing my IPv6 IP address. It is being reported as remoteIP part of the httpRequest in the log.

Comment: Can you try to modify your first rule and change the IP range to `*` or `0.0.0.0/0` to check if you can access your app using a custom domain?

Comment: @Darwin when the default rule is set to allow, the custom domain does work. That's part of the reason why I'm confused.

Comment: Can you also try to access your application in the terminal using the `curl command` 
( curl  http ://DOMAIN_NAME  )? I tried to replicate your issue and its working on my end.

Comment: @Darwin No dice. See my edit. It's looking like I'm gonna have to go the VPC route or rely on Cloudflare's firewall temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare Proxied CNAME strikes again. Turning off this feature in Cloudflare for the CNAME pointing at ghs.googlehosted.com resolved the issue after about 5 minutes.